Regarding the problem that Explorer does not open with "Ctrl + Shift + T" in Blender
I'm using Blender version 4.2.2. With the cube placed by default, I can use Ctrl + Shift + T to open Explorer and assign textures with Node Wrangler without any problems. However, when I do the same operation on a newly added cube (or any other object), the Explorer does not open, and I am unable to assign textures.
The Principled BSDF node is also selected, and Node Wrangler is enabled. Despite these conditions, the Explorer doesn't open.
